# How do I configure IntelliJ to use a specific rbenv version for Rake as an external tool?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rake

My terminal is configured to use Ruby 1.8.7, via ruby env.

If I open the Terminal in IntelliJ and do `ruby --version` I get 1.8.7, which is correct.

I have an external tool which is essentially just a Rake task. I also want this to run using my rbenv managed Ruby 1.8.7, however, when I run the task, it defaults to using the system Ruby (2.0), and then bails because the gems aren't installed here.

The verbose output points all the way back to `usr/bin/rake` - is there any way I can configure IntelliJ to use a different version of Rake?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3, on a Mac running 10.12

Comment: Ah, just tried the absolute path to the rake version I want to use and it worked.

Comment: You should upgrade from Ruby 1.8.7 to something current, especially if you use rbenv. Ruby is now on 2.4, which has all sorts of speed improvements, enhancements, and security fixes.

Comment: Yes, obviously I'm only using 1.8.7 because of a legacy project that requires it and needs occasional maintenance but has no budget for us to rebuild all the tooling and dependencies for a different ruby version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an absolute path as the Program parameter in the external tool set up to the Rake shim in rbenv:

```
/Users/someuser/.rbenv/shims/rake
```

Comment: Stack Overflow will have you wait, then will let you accept your answer as the selected solution. At that point you should set the checkmark next to the answer.